# Swift 4 - error with upperBound < lowerBound and Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKLabelNode>

Tags: swift4

I have 2 errors that took me one day without solving them.

1. The first error:  "Thread 1: Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound" when I added the function to add bonus point when touching the same node with previous node.

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   let firstTouch = touches.first!
   let positionOfTouch = firstTouch.location(in: self)
   let tappedNodes = nodes(at: positionOfTouch)
   print (tappedNodes.count)
   let firstNode = tappedNodes.first!
   handleNode(node: firstNode, bonus: 1.0)
   for index in 1...tappedNodes.count-1 {
       let current = tappedNodes[index]
       let previous = tappedNodes[index-1]
       if current.name == previous.name {
           handleNode(node: current, bonus: 2.5)
       }
       else {
           handleNode(node: current, bonus: 1)
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. The second error: " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  " appears when I add a message when a bubble is tapped in GameScene.

   ```
   var tappedScoreLabel : SKLabelNode = {
   let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Pusab")
   label.fontSize = 60
   label.fontColor = SKColor.white
   label.zPosition = 300
   return label
   ```

   } ()

   ```
   func removeTappedNode (_ node : SKNode) {
   self.run(playCorrectSoundEffect)
   node.name = ""
   node.removeAllActions()
   node.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.3),   SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
   ```

   }

Please help me. I will appreciate with your  help.

Thanks